# Why does id not come through from params to context? NextJS

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-image, nextjs-dynamic-routing

Could someone please explain why id will only populate as {ev.id} from data, as per console.log(context)? Should be pulling names from params. See below code and console.log(context)

```
const EventPage = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data);
  return <h1>Single Event</h1>;
};

export default EventPage;

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const data = await import("/data/data.json");
  const allEvents = data.allEvents;

  const allPaths = allEvents.map((path) => {
    return {
      params: {
        cat: path.city,
        id: path.id,
      },
    };
  });
console.log(allPaths);
  return {
    paths: allPaths,
    fallback: true,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  console.log(context);
  const id = context.params.id;
  const { allEvents } = await import("/data/data.json");
  const eventData = allEvents.filter((ev) => id === ev.id);

  return {
    props: { data: eventData },
  };
}
```

console.log(context)

```
{
  params: { cat: 'london', id: '{ev.id}' },
  locales: undefined,
  locale: undefined,
  defaultLocale: undefined
}
```

allPaths console.log extract

```
{ params: { cat: 'London', id: 'london-comic-con-winter' } },
  { params: { cat: 'London', id: 'hyde-park-winter-wonderland' } },
  { params: { cat: 'London', id: 'new-years-eve-in-london-2023' } },
  { params: { cat: 'london', id: "'edtech-world-summit-2022" } },
  { params: { cat: 'london', id: 'sigala-at-electric-brixton' } },
  { params: { cat: 'london', id: 'kiss-haunted-house-party-2022' } },
  { params: { cat: 'san-francisco', id: 'sf-blockchain-week' } },
```

Tried a bunch of stuff, seems to be that context should be providing id from params but it is not for some reason